# Ionic - Disable navigation animation when triggered from ion-tabs buttons

Tags: angularjs, animation, ionic-framework, navigation

I'm finding that the following is the way to disable view transitions, but I only want to disable transitions when navigating via my ion-tabs bar. Is there a way to do this in the function below?

```
angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE').config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the attribute `animation="no-animation"`.

```
<ion-nav-view animation="no-animation"></ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I don't have any custom animation code either, I'm just using the default side menu. I have an empty ion-nav-view in my index.html, but I don't (knowingly) populate that. I populate the nav view in my side menu code, which now looks like this:

    <ion-nav-view name="myView" animation="no-animation"></ion-nav-view>

Comment: <ion-nav-view name="myView" nav-transition="none"></ion-nav-view> Documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/navTransition/)